# ActiveMQ classic to ActiveMQ Artemis failover does not work

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis, failover

I'm trying to migrate from ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis.

We have a cluster of 2 active nodes that we try to migrate without impacting the consumers and producers. To do so, we stop the first node, migrate it, start it and do the same on the 2nd when the first is back up.

We are observing that the consumers/producers are not able to reconnect:

> o.a.a.t.f.FailoverTransport              |  | Failed to connect to [tcp://172.17.233.92:63616?soTimeout=30000&soWriteTimeout=30000&keepAlive=true, tcp://172.17.233.93:63616?soTimeout=30000&soWriteTimeout=30000&keepAlive=true] after: 30 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

Consumers/producers are able to connect after we have restarted them.
Is it normal behavior ?

Here is the ActiveMQ Artemis broker :

```
  <connectors>
       <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://172.17.233.92:63616</connector>
       <connector name="server_0">tcp://172.17.233.93:63616</connector>
  </connectors>
  <acceptors>
       <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://172.17.233.92:63616?protocols=OPENWIRE</acceptor>
       <acceptor name="invm">"vm://0</acceptor>
  </acceptors>
  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="cluster">
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>server_0</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
```

And here is the ActiveMQ "classic" configuration

```
     <!-- Transport protocol -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire"
                            uri="nio://172.17.233.92:63616?transport.soTimeout=15000&transport.threadName&keepAlive=true&transport.soWriteTimeout=15000&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0"
                            enableStatusMonitor="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true" updateClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" />
    </transportConnectors>

    <!-- Network of brokers setup -->
    <networkConnectors>
        <!-- we need conduit subscriptions for topics , but not for queue -->
        <networkConnector name="NC_topic" duplex="false" conduitSubscriptions="true" networkTTL="1" uri="static:(tcp://172.17.233.92:63616,tcp://172.17.233.93:63616)" decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" suppressDuplicateTopicSubscriptions="true" dynamicOnly="true">
            <excludedDestinations>
                <queue physicalName=">" />
            </excludedDestinations>
        </networkConnector>
        <!-- we need conduit subscriptions for topics , but not for queue -->
        <networkConnector name="NC_queue" duplex="false" conduitSubscriptions="false" networkTTL="1" uri="static:(tcp://172.17.233.92:63616,tcp://172.17.233.93:63616)" decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true" dynamicOnly="true">
            <excludedDestinations>
                <topic physicalName=">" />
            </excludedDestinations>
        </networkConnector>
    </networkConnectors>
```

Comment: What client library/version are you using? Can you share the client connection URL? Can you share the ActiveMQ Artemis broker.xml? Do you see the connection failure after stopping the first node?

Comment: Hi, connection URL is [tcp://172.17.233.92:63616?soTimeout=30000&soWriteTimeout=30000&keepAlive=true, tcp://172.17.233.93:63616?soTimeout=30000&soWriteTimeout=30000&keepAlive=true]. We are using ActiveMQ client 5.15.4

Comment: I've never head of anyone trying this kind "failover" before between "Classic" and Artemis so it's not clear what "normal behavior" actually is for this use-case.

Comment: Any chance you can amend your question with the contents of `broker.xml` as requested previously?

Comment: I've added Artemis and "classic" configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, we decided to first stop the 2 nodes, then upgrade and restart. It implies an interruption from consumer/producer point of view but all the subscription are done properly after the restart.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should due to `updateClusterClientsOnRemove`, if true, will update clients when a cluster is removed from the network, see [broker-side options for failover](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html#broker-side-options-for-failover).

When the first node is stopped the clients will remove it and they will not add it again because the second node with ActiveMQ Classic isn't able to connect to the first node with ActiveMQ Artemis.